# remove dynamic row after adding

Tags: php, dynamic, row

Hello How do I make a button to remove a button to remove my dynamic row? I tried

here my code

```
   script type="text/javascript">
            var counter = 0;
            $(function(){
                $('p#add_field').click(function(){
                    counter += 1;
                    $('#container').append(
                            '<strong> No.        ' + counter + '</strong>' 
                            + 
                            '<strong>       ........................        Client ' + counter + '</strong><br />' 
                            +
                            '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" />'
                            +
                            '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfieldstest[]' + '" type="text" /><br />'
); });});
       </script>
```

my form :

```
  <input type="submit" name="retour"  value="retour"  />
                            </form>
                            <?php
                         mysql_close();
                        }  ?> <?php if (!isset($_POST['submit_val'])) { ?>
                            <form method="post" action="">
                                <div id="container"> 
                              <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>Click To Add more info</span></a></p>  </div>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit_val"  value="Submit"  />
```

Comment: You didn't try to make a remove button.  All that code is for adding.

Comment: I just didn'T show it cause it was really lame.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to wrap the row in a tag like a `div`, then you you can dynamically remove that element, like so (if you're using jquery):

```
<div>
    your content here...
    <button onClick="$(this).parent('div').remove()">remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using jquery

Comment: keep in mind that your counter will still be incrementing, so if you need to keep track of it, you'll probably need to do the removing in a function that can access your counter.

Comment: so that will better if I press a button I'll decrement and if I decrement last row = delete. Or how to verify if all last row is complete button addrow is visible if not is hidden ( so not obligate to use a remove button)

Comment: Can I do something like this ?   `code   $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        counter += 1;
        $('#container').append(
                '<strong> No.        ' + counter + '</strong>' 
                + 
                '<strong>       ........................        Client ' + counter + '</strong><br />' 
                +
                '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" />'
                +'<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfieldstest[]' + '" type="text" /><br />'+
'<button onClick="$(this).parent('div').remove()">remove</button>' );
`